MongoEngineConversionError: DynamicField
Can't really find out what is the problem. I get the error when running django+graphql+mongo project:

Don't know how to convert the MongoEngine field
<mongoengine.fields.DynamicField object at 0x000001B86AC92690> (<class
'mongoengine.fields.DynamicField'>)

class TableRowCellType(MongoengineObjectType):
    class Meta:
    model = TableRowCell

class TableRowCell(EmbeddedDocument):
    value = DynamicField()


